# Why does this cause my site to redirect to secure.secure.*root domain*.com?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, subdomain

Here is the rewrite rule I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)secure.\ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://secure.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This rule is supposed to be applied if the port is 443 (SSL port) and if the requested domain does not start with secure or www.secure .

Instead, it redirects to secure.secure and then returns a 404 error. Alternatively, if I remove the secure from rewrite rule creating

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)secure.\ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I get a too many redirects error.

I admit, I am not a mod_rewrite expert, but I consider myself able to function with referring to the documentation. On this however, I am stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Josh, welcome to SO. If you don't get a good answer here, you might try serverfault.com.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I have faith in corrupting the stack however!

Answer (score 1):

The grouping `(www.)` is not conditional. This should be something like `(www.)?`.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html for more extensive documentation.

Comment: So it should be : `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?secure.\ [NC]`

Comment: That regrettably did not fix the issue, although I'll up-vote because you found a syntax error.

Comment: Hmm, lets see. Other things that occur to me: you could use the HTTPS var (`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`) instead of the port. Also in the HTTP_HOST rule, I do not get the escaping of the dot, thus I would imagine something like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?secure\. [NC]`. I can't see anything other than that, so I hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up simply abandoning the idea of dynamically specifying the subdomain and instead I explicitly wrote the whole thing out:

    `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure.mysite.com$ [NC]

    RewriteRule (.*) https://secure.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`